# I have try to upload and store the files and textbox values in mysql using angularjs

Tags: php, html, mysql, angularjs

I have try to upload  and store the files and textbox values in mysql using angularjs but got error.

```
Please find the below code.

<form action="" name="main" id="main"  ng-controller='addFileCtrl' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="width:100% !important;">
<fieldset>
<ol>
         <div class="col-md-6">
            <li>
            <label>
                File: (*) 
                </label>
                <input type="file" size="30" name="file_user" style="width:400px" id="file_user" ng-model='resume.file_user' required>
                </li>
             <li>
            <label>
                Description:
                </label>
                <textarea cols="60" rows="5" name="file_description" style="width:400px" id="file_description"  ng-model='resume.description'></textarea>
                </li>  
                <li> &nbsp; </li>
                <li style="padding-right:150px">
            <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"  ng-click="upload_submit()" value="Add" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"> Add</button>
                </li>    
</div>
</ol>   
</fieldset>             
</form>
```

This is my controller page.

```
app.controller('addresumeCtrl',function ($scope,$http,$location,$rootScope) {

    $scope.upload_submit = function() {
        $http.post('ajax/upload_resume.php',$scope.resume
        )
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(data);
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config){

        });


    }


});
```

Please any one help the myscript. what is wrong in a script